# Python fabric.api backslash hell

Tags: python, fabric, backslash

I'm new to python and fabric api. I'm trying to use the sudo functionality to run a sed command in bash terminal which insert some text after a particular line of text is found. Some of the text I'm trying to insert into the file I'm modifying contains backslashes which seem to either be ignored by fabric or cause syntax errors. I've tried "shell=true" and "shell=false" options but still no luck. How can I escape the backslash? It seems "shell=true" only escapes $ and ". My Code below.

sudo (' sed -i "/sometext/a textwith\backslash" /home/me/somefile.txt',shell=True)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try prefixing your string with `r`, which means that it will be interpreted as a raw string:

```
sudo (r' sed -i "/sometext/a textwith\backslash" /home/me/somefile.txt',shell=True)
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) for additional information on string literals and their usage in Python.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I'm still not having any luck. Though the strange thing is that if I add exactly 13 backslash's it works!? I'll keep playing........

Answer (score 4):

OK, finally worked this out. RocketDonkey was correct. Needed to prefix with "r" but also needed to set "shell=False". This allowed what ever worked directly in the bash terminal to work when being called from fabric.api.

Thanks RocketDonkey!!

Comment: Awesome! Ha I was wracking my brain trying to figure out what the deal was - totally overlooked the shell part. Smart catch on your part - +1!

Comment: You don't need to prefix it with r. Just setting `shell=False` worked for me.

Comment: This is an old post but I'm stuck on this. I tried adding r'mystring' and set the shell to false, but no luck. I'm getting the error.../bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file